# AJAX POST request: 403 Forbidden returned in Chrome and Firefox but not with curl

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox, curl

I am performing a simple POST request using AJAX. The request requires basic authentication.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://bjpeter.ehawaii.gov:8080/ai-gateway/service/BRIM.json",
    data: '{"lang":"en","timestamp":"2017-08-03T20:16:18.273Z","result":{"parameters":{"entity":"ALOHA"}}}',
    headers: {
        "Accept" : "application/json",
        "Content-Type" : "application/json",
        "Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa("john:heaven")
    },
    success: function(result) {
        $("#result").val(result);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        $("#result").val(status + ": " + error);
    }
});
```

`bjpeter.ehawaii.gov:8080` points to my machine from which the AJAX call is made. I am supposed to get JSON data in the response.

However, in Chrome, the response was `403 Forbidden`:
[image]

Firefox also returned `403 Forbidden`:
[image]

But when I used `curl`, JSON data was returned, as expected:

```
curl -v -u john:heaven -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{"lang":"en","timestamp":"2017-08-03T20:16:18.273Z","result":{"parameters":{"entity":"ALOHA"}}}' http://bjpeter.ehawaii.gov:8080/ai-gateway/service/BRIM.json
```

[image]

Why is Chrome and Firefox returning `403 Forbidden` instead of JSON data? I noticed that the remote address is 127.0.0.1:8080 in Chrome and ::1 in Firefox.

Comment: I double-checked just now. Yes, the btoa() function replaced the final K with =. I looked at the request generated by curl and it is also am9objpoZWF2ZW4=.

Comment: Sorry for the noise, I was wrong. You could add more of the browsers' headers to the curl request to try to see if you thus can trigger the 403 that way and spot which header that causes it. `User-Agent` maybe?